# AS3 Error 1119 undefined property with static type Function

Tags: function, actionscript-3, hide

I am new to as3 and programming in general and I want to ask how to hide 'function grid()' entirely when 'mc_gameover' event is clicked?

I have tried adjusting its visibility and removing the children of the 'tile' variable, using 'stage.parent.removeChild(tile);', but it only removes one tile.

```
function grid(): void

{

mc_gameover.btn_mainmenu.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, hidetile);

function hidetile(event:MouseEvent):void
{   

grid.visible= false;
removeChild(tile);

}   
    
    
for(var i:int = 0; i < rows; i++){

for(var j:int = 0; j < columns; j++){

var tile:Sprite = new Tile(); //get tile from the library

//Arrange tiles to form a grid

tile.x = (headWidth/2) + (j * headWidth);

tile.y = (headWidth/2) + (i * headWidth);

addChild(tile);
    

}

}


}

grid();
```

Comment: The **grid** is a function/method. It is not a display-able object. You cannot make a function [in]visible. It makes no sense. Clarify, what is that you a trying to achieve.

Comment: Initially, I wanted to hide the parent 'tile' sprite which effectively hides the grid using removeChild(tile); but it only hides a single tile and I don't think it's hiding the parent tile at all even if I use parent.removeChild(tile); 

So, as a last resort I wanted to hide the grid altogether, although I just learned that that isn't possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you think it is not possible? It is possible in several ways. The most straightforward and comprehensible one is to devise a container for all the things you want to show/hide at once.

```
// Might not be a mandatory section here,
// but will be when you get to work with classes.
import Tile;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

// Container for all the tiles.
var WholeGrid:Sprite;

// Do not nest functions.
// Although it is possible, it is not a good thing to do.
function hideGrid(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    // Use tabs to keep your code structured and readable.
    if (WholeGrid)
    {
        WholeGrid.visible = false;
    }
}

function arrangeGrid():void
{
    // Create the container, if necessary. Clean and show it otherwise.
    if (WholeGrid)
    {
        WholeGrid.removeChildren();
        WholeGrid.visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        WholeGrid = new Sprite;
        addChild(WholeGrid);
    }
    
    mc_gameover.btn_mainmenu.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, hideGrid);
  
    for (var i:int = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (var j:int = 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            // Instantiate a new tile from library class.
            var tile:Sprite = new Tile;
            
            // Arrange the tile to form a grid.
            // No need for brackets here, as * and / has prioroty.
            tile.x = headWidth / 2 + j * headWidth;
            tile.y = headWidth / 2 + i * headWidth;
            
            // Add the tile to the container.
            WholeGrid.addChild(tile);
        }
    }
}

// Create and arrange the grid.
arrangeGrid();
```

Comment: Hello! thank you very much, it works as intended. Looking at your code, it's much easier to navigate and read, and doesn't come out as undefined.

Comment: Hello, i'd like to thank you again since I can study your code and apply it to more of my dirty code. 'import' is a useful thing, what is import called?

Comment: @webdog The **import** instruction tells the compiler (and also you) which classes you are going to use in the given context (the frame script in your case).